# Nodejs: wait for multiple requests to return a response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, asynchronous

I looked over the internet looking for an answer but I didn't find.

I studied a bit about the event loop thanks to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ amazing video.

still my problem is not solved. I tried with promises and callback but my problem is over that. because I call a function that inside there is asynchronous function so if I put the callback, it will wait for the end of the function not the asynchrounous function within it.

So I ask you help. I beg help XD I am getting know more and more javascript so thats my question:

I have a nodejs express angular app. I have a form in the front end. I make a post request with this form to my node server than I grab this data I process it and I start to make 6 request to a server. at the end of this 6 request I need to send back the data to the front end so now I tell you what I dont get

```
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
    var from = (new Date(req.body.from)).getTime();
    var to = (new Date(req.body.to)).getTime();
    var partner = req.body.partner;
    var POS = req.body.POS;

    Request.request(from,to,partner,POS);
    res.send("data")
}
```

this is about my handling of the form as you can see the problem is that when I call "Request.request" even if I put a call back will it will finish before the data come since "request.request" is a synchronous function and all the 6 request are asynchronous.

I give you an hint of are are made my requests its quite a lot of once but is easier if I sum it.

```
Request.request(){
    res.end(){
        savedata**;
        if (recursionIndex<y)
            indexRequest();
        else
            bodyRequest()
    } //async request

    req.end(){}
}
```

basically once you define the number of time you want to repeat the function you are done. Now what I need is to wait till the end of everything and than give back the whole data to angular

```
bodyRequest(){
    // Same logic of before I didnt use any callback I just used recursion
}
```

now my question is since I am just using recursion how can I make the whole thing async how can I wrap up everything and give back the data once the last recursion happen?

Comment: Your pseudocode is too pseudo. Looks like a Promise.all usecase.

Comment: Did you take a look at [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) module? Depending on what you want to achieve `async.waterfall` or `async.series` could help you handling the 6 requests in a clean way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I got the answer,

```
app.post('/api/todos', function(req, res) {
   var from = (new Date(req.body.from)).getTime();
   var to = (new Date(req.body.to)).getTime();
   var partner = req.body.partner;
   var POS = req.body.POS;

   Request.request(from,to,partner,POS,res);

   //res.send("data")
    }
```

I pass "res" to my Request.request and through all the subfunction and the trick is done!

since res is an object that possesses the function to answer the POST request coming from angular doesn't matter when you call it but you need the object.
thanks everyone for their attention!